# how to get the text field value and call them by the tag value of that text field

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertcontroller

I have two textFields.I din't globally declared.So its inside my `UIAlertController`. Now the `textFields` are:

```
text.tag = 100
text2.tag = 200
```

So i have one selector method to for `textfield2`In that method i need to call the `textfield1` value is having the string (hello) or not.Here my code :

Question Edited --

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do like

**Choice-1**

> you can access Direct Tags

```
-(void)textDidChange:(UITextField *)textField
    {

if (textField.text.length > 0) {


        if (textField.tag == 100) // textField1
        {

                if ([textField.text containsString:@"@"])
                    NSLog(@"Valid");
                 else
                    NSLog(@"Invalid");                    
        }
          else 
         {
           //textField2 work
         }      

}

}
```

**Choice-2**

> you can access Via Object Name

```
-(void)textDidChange:(UITextField *)textField
    {

if (textField.text.length > 0) {


        if (textField == textField1) // 100
        {

                if ([textField.text containsString:@"@"])
                    NSLog(@"Valid");
                 else
                    NSLog(@"Invalid");                    
        }
          else 
         {
           //textField2 work
         }      

}

}
```

**Choice-3**

> I have two text field.I din't globally declared. - for your Concept then Do like

```
- (void)textDidChange:(UITextField *)sender
{
UIAlertController *alertController = (UIAlertController *)self.presentedViewController;
 if (alertController)
 {
UITextField *txt1 = alertController.textFields.firstObject;
 UITextField *txt2 = alertController.textFields.lastObject;


if (textField.text.length > 0) {


        if (textField == txt1) // 100
        {

                if ([textField.text containsString:@"@"])
                    NSLog(@"Valid");
                 else
                    NSLog(@"Invalid");                    
        }
          else 
         {
           //textField2 work
         }      

   }
}
```

Comment: `TextField1` has no target added, so this will not work

Answer (score 1):

Please do like this

```
-(void)textDidChange:(UITextField *)textField
    {

if(textField.tag == 100){// do stuff here

}else if(textField.tag == 200){
}

if (textField.text.length > 0) {

                NSString *string = textField.text; // Here i have to call my first textfield value using tag value 

                if ([string containsString:@"@"]) {
                    NSLog(@"Valid");
                } else {
                    NSLog(@"Invalid");
                }



}

}
```

Comment: `TextField1` has no target added, so this will not work

Comment: @mack Yes, please check and update me if it is not working... :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this create one instance variable of type `UITextField` and initialize this textField with your `alertController` textField's.

```
UITextField txtField;

[alertController addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler:^(UITextField *textField1) {
    textField1.placeholder = @"iCloud ID";
    txtField = textField1;
}];
```

Now use this `textField` inside your method of `textField2`

```
-(void)textDidChange:(UITextField *)textField {
    if (textField.text.length > 0) {
         NSString *string = txtField.text; // Here you will get first textfield value
         if ([string containsString:@"@"]) {
              NSLog(@"Valid");
         } else {
              NSLog(@"Invalid");
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: where you used this `NSString text1`

Comment: Its up to op where he want to use

Answer (score 0):

you can use `textFields` Property

> The array of text fields displayed by the alert. (read-only)

Please try it:

```
-(void)textDidChange:(UITextField *)textField
{
    if (textField.text.length > 0) {

        for (UITextField *alertTextField in alertController.textFields) {

            if(alertTextField.tag == 100){   // first textfield

                NSString *string = alertTextField.text;

                if ([string containsString:@"@"]) {
                    NSLog(@"Valid");
                } else {
                    NSLog(@"Invalid");
                }
               break; 
            }
        } 
    } 
}
```